# property 'pc2' of feature '1_1_1_1_0_0' is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine

while using google earth engine to classify the land use of an area, the error of property 'pc2' of feature '1_1_1_1_0_0' is missing, appears.
actually this error appears for all bands of my testing data. here is my code:

```
var classesT = t_forest_2001.merge(t_rice_2001).merge(t_dryfarm_2001).merge(t_village_2001)
  .merge(t_water_2001) .merge(t_bare_2001);
  print(classesT);
  Map.addLayer(classesT ,{}, 'test');
  var bands = ['PC2','PC1','slope', 'NDWI','NDVI','NDBI','texture'];
 var testing = classified.sampleRegions({
                                       collection: classesT,
                                       properties:['landuse'],
                                       scale: 30
                                                      });

//var con=  testing.errorMatrix('landuse','classification')
//print ('accu',con.producersAccuracy().project([0]));                                                    
  //var classifiedT = testing.select(bands).classify(classifier);
  Map.addLayer(classified ,{min:0, max:5, palette: ['#358521', '#63ff60',
  '#ffb783', '#be3939','#68f8ff','#ffe78f']},'classification');

 var confusionMatrix = ee.ConfusionMatrix(testing.classify(classifier)
                     .errorMatrix({
                       actual: 'landuse', 
                       predicted: 'classification'
                                     }));
print('Test:', confusionMatrix);
print('Overall Accuracy Test:', confusionMatrix.accuracy());
print('kappa Test:', confusionMatrix.kappa());
print('Producers Accuracy Test:', confusionMatrix.producersAccuracy());
print('Consumers Accuracy Test:', confusionMatrix.consumersAccuracy());
```